# What does Shoko say to Yuzuru in chapter 12?

Tags: koe-no-katachi, sign-language

In chapter 12 of *A Silent Voice*, collected in volume 2, Shoko has a fight with her sister Yuzuru, angry with her for getting Shoya in trouble when he helped her. Yuzuru's lines are spoken, but Shoko signs with no translation given. The chapter features four panels of Shoko signing across two pages; her words in the last are harsh enough that Yuzuru breaks down crying and runs away.

[image: Chapter 12 pages 8 - 9]

(I recognize that it may not be possible to recognize full sentences from a single manga panel each.)

Comment: While it really isn't vital to the story that it is translated, all bar the last are guessable to what Shoko was saying. Although I am curious what was said in the last one (because there was no reply).

Comment: It would be Japanese Sign Language, which is distinct from ASL, BSL and other English world sign languages. This time & last time I googled there are no known English JSL resources on the web. If you post the images I might be able to guess if there is context and if the sign is iconic (i.e. looks like what it means), but few signs are iconic, (i.e. usually they are abstract and can't be guessed by looking at them any more than you could guess "Zou" from hearing it.

Comment: @MatthewMartin ask and the internet delivers. Fair use: the image is just the necessary section of the work, and is of low-resolution. Required to illustrate the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Panel 3 <sub>(Not sure about this one)</sub>

Sign: [*Me* (eye)](https://cgi2.nhk.or.jp/signlanguage/enquete.cgi?md=syllabary&dno=34) - [you](https://cgi2.nhk.or.jp/signlanguage/enquete.cgi?dno=615) - [heart](https://cgi2.nhk.or.jp/signlanguage/enquete.cgi?dno=5325)
Meaning: What's with that look? What are you thinking?

Or,

Sign: [You](https://cgi2.nhk.or.jp/signlanguage/enquete.cgi?dno=615) - [money](https://cgi2.nhk.or.jp/signlanguage/enquete.cgi?dno=723) - [receive](https://cgi2.nhk.or.jp/signlanguage/enquete.cgi?dno=1230)
Meaning: Did you receive money?

Panel 4

Sign: [He](https://cgi2.nhk.or.jp/signlanguage/enquete.cgi?dno=7092) - [sorry](https://cgi2.nhk.or.jp/signlanguage/enquete.cgi?dno=845)
Meaning: Apologize to him (Shoya)

Panel 5

Sign: [Can't be helped](https://cgi2.nhk.or.jp/signlanguage/enquete.cgi?dno=4367) - [together](https://cgi2.nhk.or.jp/signlanguage/enquete.cgi?dno=2367) -
 [apologize](https://cgi2.nhk.or.jp/signlanguage/enquete.cgi?dno=4715)
Meaning: Can't be helped, let's go apologize together

Panel 7

> Sign: [I](https://cgi2.nhk.or.jp/signlanguage/enquete.cgi?dno=4494) - [leave it alone](https://cgi2.nhk.or.jp/signlanguage/enquete.cgi?dno=7547) - [you](https://cgi2.nhk.or.jp/signlanguage/enquete.cgi?dno=615)
>  Meaning: I don't need you, do what you want!

---

References: [item777's blog (Japanese)](http://item777.seesaa.net/article/412563559.html), [los-endos' blog (Japanese)](http://los-endos.hatenablog.com/entry/20160819/1471617024).

Comment: @ShayGuy You could mark this as accepted answer i guess